# reference to a <div> within an <xsl:template>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

I am using XSL, and trying to get a template to change appearances depending on a radio click. Here is my xsl:

```
    <xsl:template name="process">
       <div id="option1" style="display:none"/>
           <tr>
              <b> Processing Option 1 </b>
           </tr>
       </div>
       <div id="option2"/>
           <tr>
              <b> Processing Option 2 </b>
           </tr>
       </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

How would I access the two different `<div>`'s? My intention is to access these two different `<div>`'s through buttons; when one button is clicked, the template will show option 1, and when another is clicked, option 2 will show.

I have the buttons set up, but Im not sure how to access these 's and switch them from display:none, to display:block, and from display:block, to display:none.

Please let me know what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that this xml code gets parsed into an xml document, you can grab the nodes with `getElementsByTagName` or some xpath expression, then compare those ids with the id the user clicked.

Comment: Any client-side Javascript reacting after a click of a radio button is executed after the XSLT transformation has been done so your script is simply dealing with the HTML result of the transformation and will not be different from any script included in a static HTML document. Your HTML however is very strange given that you have put a `tr` element into a `div` (a `tr` element belongs into a `table` or into a table section like `tbody`, `thead`) and a `b` element into a `tr` (the allowed children of a `tr` are `th` and `td`). So you need to start fixing your HTML to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using XSL, and trying to get a template to change appearances depending on a radio click.

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hide-show.xml"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
      <style>
        .folder input[type='radio']:checked + blockquote { display: block; }
        .folder input[type='radio']  + blockquote { display: none; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="folder">
        <div>Blue
        <input type="radio" name="color"/>
        <blockquote>hi</blockquote>
        </div>
        <div>Red
        <input type="radio" name="color"/>
        <blockquote>bye</blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This self-contained stylesheet works when saved as `hide-show.xml`.